# What are the large round dark "holes" in this NASA Hubble image of the Crab Nebula?

Tags: hubble-telescope, nebula

I came across this image of the Crab Nebula taken from NASA Hubble telescope. What are the large round "holes" and how are they formed?

[image]

Comment: What a great question - the arrows make it really clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [my deleted answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18898/2153) to [your previous question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18893/2153) covers this well, so I'll add it here.

These two spots are known as **the east and west bays** of the Crab Nebula. They appear to be the result of a torus partially encircling a section of the nebula. The pulsar's magnetic field interacts with the gas and dust in the torus, which blocks [synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation) from gases in the nebula. It has been conjectured that the torus is the result of a $\sim0.1M_{\odot}$ ejection of material from a circumstellar disk prior to the supernova, based on studies of the proper motion of gas on the edges of both bays.

#### References

- [Fesen et al. (1992)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1992ApJ...399..599F)
- [Hester et al. (1995)](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/53632/)

We can also rule out that this is the result of a defect in Hubble, because these features have been observed in [different wavelengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Crab_Nebula_in_Multiple_Wavelengths.png), including infrared, visible, ultraviolet, and x-ray (though not in radio or gamma-ray wavelengths):

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of Wikipedia user Hunster under [the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).</sup>

The infrared, ultraviolet, and x-ray images come from the Spitzer Space Telescope, the SWIFT observatory, and the Chandra observatory, respectively.

Comment: Beautiful!  I've "borrowed" the image and info for [this question](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18905/7982).